# Scraping Twitter posts using puppeteer.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, twitter, puppeteer

I'm trying to make my personal twitter post scraper but it seems to be harder than I tought it would be.

The idea is firstly to grab the div post than go through them and eventually get the post text.

It's not going how I imagine it, currently I'm getting only an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var fs = require('fs');

async function getQuotes(){

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://twitter.com/Twitter', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}); // page url
   
    const result = await page.$$eval('div.css-901oao.r-jwli3a.r-1qd0xha.r-a023e6.r-16dba41.r-ad9z0x.r-bcqeeo.r-bnwqim.r-qvutc0', rows => {
        return rows.map(row =>{
            const properties = {};
            const post = row.querySelector('span.css-901oao.css-16my406.r-1qd0xha.r-ad9z0x.r-bcqeeo.r-qvutc0');
            properties.text = post.innerText;
            return properties;
        });
    });
    console.log(result);
    browser.close();
}
getQuotes();
```

Comment: FYI: You won't be able to rely on classes like `css-901oao` as they will change as soon as Twitter changes the CSS (they are a checksum of the CSS properties)

Comment: Yes, I'm quite aware of that, and it's not really a problem because I can readjust the classes when it would be needed. Main problem now is that I can't make it work at all as I'm not very familiar with puppeteer, and scraping in general.

Comment: Try `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false})` instead of `true`.

Comment: Web scraping the Twitter web site is against the terms of service - use the official API.

Comment: @AndyPiper that's equivalent of saying preforming a GET request is against the terms of service, which to read, would require a preforming a GET request, therefor, reading the terms of service, is against the terms of service.

Comment: I’ll leave you to decide on what is allowed then. I’m telling you what the terms very VERY clearly state. You can do what you want with the information.

Answer (score 7):

Each tweet is an [`article`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article) element. The content of each tweet seems to be in a `div` with the `lang` attribute.

Knowing that, we can change your selector to `article div[lang]`

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://twitter.com/Twitter', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

  const results = await page.$$eval('article div[lang]', (tweets) => tweets.map((tweet) => tweet.textContent));
  console.log(results);

  browser.close();
})();
```

This outputs:

```js
[
  'if you had a twitter before 2020 rt this',
  'some of you hating...\n\nbut we see you Fleeting ',
  'That thing you didn’t Tweet but wanted to but didn’t but got so close but then were like nah. \n' +
    '\n' +
    'We have a place for that now—Fleets! \n' +
    '\n' +
    'Rolling out to everyone starting today.'
]
```

Of course you still have to work around infinite scrolling and you'll probably encounter more issues down the line, but that's hopefully enough to get you started.

---

However, you probably shouldn't do this to begin with.

According to [Twitter Terms of Service](https://twitter.com/en/tos) (emphasis mine):

> […] access or search or attempt to access or search the Services by any means (automated or otherwise) other than through our currently available, published interfaces that are provided by Twitter (and only pursuant to the applicable terms and conditions), unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Twitter (NOTE: crawling the Services is permissible if done in accordance with the provisions of the robots.txt file, however, **scraping the Services without the prior consent of Twitter is expressly prohibited**); […]